# How can I call stored procedure returning 2 tables in a controller in mvc entity framework 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures, table-valued-parameters

I have a stored procedure which returns 2 tables. How can I call this stored procedure from a controller in MVC.
(I'm using Entity Framework 4)

---

### Stored procedure:

```
create proc [dbo].[sp_list33](@emp dbo.list READONLY )
as
select * from dbo.Items
select * from dbo.dept
```

---

Here 'list' is a userdefined table type for passing table valued parameter.

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[list] AS TABLE(
    [eid] [int] NULL,
    [name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [age] [int] NULL
)
```

### In controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Onclick(int id)
        {

            using (examemployeeEntities1 eee = new examemployeeEntities1())
            {
                //Create table value parameter
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                dt.Columns.Add("eid");
                dt.Columns.Add("name");
                dt.Columns.Add("age");
                dt.Rows.Add(1, "john", 21);
                dt.Rows.Add(2, "albert", 22);
                dt.Rows.Add(3, "martin", 33);

                SqlParameter emp1 = new SqlParameter("@emp", SqlDbType.Structured);
                emp1.Value = dt;
                emp1.TypeName = "list";

                //eee.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("EXEC sp_list4 @emp",emp1);
                var resp = eee.Database.SqlQuery<Item>("exec sp_list33 @emp", emp1);

                return Json(resp.ToList());  
            }
         }
```

In view:
paragraph id is "sdf" and button id is "asd"!!!!!

### Script:

```
 $("#asd").click(function () {

        var a = 1;
        var content = "<table><th>Id</th><th>Name </th><th>Age</th></tr>";
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Home/Onclick/',
            data: { 'id': a },
            datatype: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                    content += "<tr>";
                    content += "<td style=\"background-color:White\">" + data[i].eid + "</td>";
                    content += "<td style=\"background-color:White\">" + data[i].name + "</td>";
                    content += "<td style=\"background-color:White\">" + data[i].age + "</td>";
                    content += "</tr>";
                });
                content += "</table>";
                $('#sdf').html(content);
                alert("success");
            },
            error: function () {
            }
        });

    });
```

Result displays content in the Item table only. How to get two entities from stored procedure? It is only retrieving the first select statement. Can any one help me to solve this..?

Comment: Is there a way you can use Entity framework 5?

Comment: Sorry, it is an ongoing one that use entity framework 4.

Comment: can't we use that in EF4??

Comment: upgrading would probably be easier, esp. if you're using nuget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are not using EF5, you can't go [the easy way](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj691402.aspx)

As Microsoft stated in that link:

> "Prior to EF5, Entity Framework would allow the stored procedure to be called but would only return the first result set to the calling code."

But there is always a work-around. Follow [this steps](http://blogs.infosupport.com/ado-net-entity-framework-advanced-scenarios-working-with-stored-procedures-that-return-multiple-resultsets/) and you will be able to achieve it. Although is not a very straight forward solution.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for the above link. Thats the kind of article i wanted. But while compiling the application in the article ,it shows 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

Comment: No worries. Glad I can help. I see, did you installed the EF Extensions? http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EFExtensions

Comment: Thank you, I just sorted out the problem by myself!! :)